# Startup behavior in Jboss

Tags: jboss, startup

I want to force the specific applications startup order deployed to `JBoss EAP 7.3.5.GA`, however I've not found any other solution than specifying the application's dependencies directly in the ear configuration file `jboss-all.xml` added to `app.ear/META-INF`.

In WebSphere there is a neat and simple solution to indicate the order of applications startup:
[image]

From the WAS help: "Specifies the order in which applications are started. Lower values start earlier."

**Question is**:

1. Is it possible to do it similarly in JBoss
2. If not why, seems to me to be a basic functionality
3. If not, how to do it

Comment: Given you're referring to EAP I assume you've got a support contract and can view https://access.redhat.com/solutions/88763. This if for JBoss EAP 6, but should work for JBoss EAP 7 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JamesR.Perkins unfortunately me personally I don't have Red Hat subscription, so I can't view this post. If you know and can provide the solution here I'll be grateful.

Comment: This is for JBoss AS 7, but should work for WildFly and JBoss EAP 7 as well http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-deploy/configuring-jboss-as-7-deployment-order.

Comment: You suggest using .xml configuration files, I'd like to know if there is an option similar to what is in WAS. If not do you know why -- it is quite crucial functionality?

Comment: An XML config in the deployment is the only way https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications#control_order_deployments.

Comment: okay, thanks for the information